# Exporting into PDF with Libreoffice ?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I am facing problem while exporting LibreOffice calc file into PDF. I want it to be in single sheet 1 page but its becoming 2 pages.

Comment: Does [this answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/675286/84724) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Document consists only of 1 page ? That happend to me a few times. Another posibillity is the opening "export as PDF" dialog gives you the posibillity to define the Range you want to export.

**All**

**Pages**

**Selection**

You could try to set **Pages** to **1** there.